# Why there is no generic list in WPF Settings?

Tags: c#, wpf, settings

I wanted to save a List of objects in a WPF application using the Settings, but there is no such collection type. My app is very simple, so I didn't want to use any database, XML or other options.
I guess that Settings should be used for storing the settings (nothing insightful...), but why collections like Stack or Queue are still available?

Screenshots from project's Settings:

[image: In System.Collections]

[image: In System.Collections.Specialized]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is specification of generic type. How will you specify the generic type, if you chose the type of your setting `List<T>`, where will you specify `T`? So there are collections which works with `object`s and boxing, e.g. `ArrayList`.